# Can you use push notifications and in app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, apple-push-notifications

I noticed that apps that use push notifications and in app purchases need unique bundle identifiers for the various features they entail.

Would there be a conflict of interests or can you use both features in the same app?

Comment: yes, you can use both features

Comment: How do you go about using both the bundle identifier you created for your push notification app and the bundle identifier you created for your in app purchase app in the same app?

Comment: You only have one bundle identifier; this is for your app. In app purchase items have a product identifier. To send a push your need the certificate for your app and the tokenid from the device that was provided when it registered for push notifications.

Comment: Im looking at this in app purchase tutorial and it says a bundle id needs to be created? https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

Comment: So the same bundle Id can be used for both apps? Im trying to combine 2 apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Bundle identifiers allow the Apple ecosystem to identify your particular app between all the millions(?) other ones. Having one bundle id, and only one, is absolutely ok and intended. You can use all the services in parallel like remote notifications, in app purchases and others. All these services live in their own 'universe' and don't care if you also use your app with another service.